# Partition key generation for RDBMS sharding

Tags: rdbms, guid, sharding

Consider I have very huge table that needs to be sharded across the RDBMS cluster. I need to decide on the partitioning key on which to shard the table across. Obviously this partition key can’t be an artificial key (example: auto-generated primary key column), because the application needs to hold the logic of figuring out the shard depends on the natural key from request data. Consider the following situation

1. If the natural key is not evenly distributed in the system

   ```
     a)    Is it a good idea to even consider this table for sharding ?
   ```
2. Is there a way to generate a GUID based on the natural key and evenly distribute it across the cluster?
3. what can be an efficient algorithm to generate a GUID based on the natural key.

Answer (score 0):

If the key is not evenly distributed it might not have any difference whether the table is partitioned or not. It will have to read almost same amount of rows in order to fulfil the query. Remember, partitioning will not always increase the performance. Reading across partitions will might be slower. So make sure you analyse all the query needs before selecting the partition key.

I can't recall any function which can generate partition key for this case. There are functions to generate GUIDs or MD5 for your data but the result will be worst than natural key that you have. The results will be more towards to unique values. Also it will drop the performance as each and every request it has to run additional logics.

Also please consider purging old or unused data. Once that is done you might not have partitioning need.